# GnuPG for Java library ant build issue/bug

Tags: java, ant, cryptography, gnupg

I'm working `GnuPG Java API` to encrypt/decrypt files.
 Googled and found a Java Wrapper [`GnuPG for Java`](https://github.com/guardianproject/gnupg-for-java), Java wrapper for `GPGME(GnuPG Made Easy,C language library)`.
 Official website also referring [this](https://github.com/guardianproject/gnupg-for-java) as the Java wrapper.
 So followed the instructions, set up `ant` and tried to run `ant clean release`
 it is throwing errors.
But maven build working and jar file also generated.
Following error occured while running `ant`.

```
 C:\Users\user\Desktop\MFT\gnupg-for-java-master>ant clean release
Buildfile: C:\Users\user\Desktop\MFT\gnupg-for-java-master\build.xml

clean-native:
     [exec] rm -f GnuPGContext.o GnuPGData.o GnuPGGenkeyResult.o GnuPGKey.o GnuPGSignature.o gpgmeutils.o *~
     [exec] rm -f C:\Users\user\Desktop\MFT\gnupg-for-java-master\build/gnupg-for-java.dll
     [exec] rm -f  com_freiheit_gnupg_GnuPGContext.h  com_freiheit_gnupg_GnuPGData.h  com_freiheit_gnupg_GnuPGGenkeyResult.h  com_freiheit_gnupg_GnuPG
Key.h  com_freiheit_gnupg_GnuPGSignature.h

clean:
   [delete] Deleting directory C:\Users\user\Desktop\MFT\gnupg-for-java-master\build\classes

prepare:

compile-java:
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Users\user\Desktop\MFT\gnupg-for-java-master\build\classes
    [javac] C:\Users\user\Desktop\MFT\gnupg-for-java-master\build.xml:21: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=l
ast; set to false for repeatable builds
    [javac] Compiling 8 source files to C:\Users\user\Desktop\MFT\gnupg-for-java-master\build\classes

gen-jni-headers:

prepare:

compile-java:
    [javac] C:\Users\user\Desktop\MFT\gnupg-for-java-master\build.xml:21: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=l
ast; set to false for repeatable builds

generate-jni-headers:
     [exec] C:\Program Files (x86)/Java/jdk1.7.0_51/bin/javah -classpath C:\Users\user\Desktop\MFT\gnupg-for-java-master\build\classes -jni  com.freih
eit.gnupg.GnuPGContext  com.freiheit.gnupg.GnuPGData  com.freiheit.gnupg.GnuPGGenkeyResult  com.freiheit.gnupg.GnuPGKey  com.freiheit.gnupg.GnuPGSigna
ture
     [exec] /bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
     [exec] /bin/sh: -c: line 0: `C:\Program Files (x86)/Java/jdk1.7.0_51/bin/javah -classpath C:\Users\user\Desktop\MFT\gnupg-for-java-master\build\c
lasses -jni  com.freiheit.gnupg.GnuPGContext  com.freiheit.gnupg.GnuPGData  com.freiheit.gnupg.GnuPGGenkeyResult  com.freiheit.gnupg.GnuPGKey  com.fre
iheit.gnupg.GnuPGSignature'
     [exec] make: *** [com_freiheit_gnupg_GnuPGContext.h] Error 2

BUILD FAILED
C:\Users\user\Desktop\MFT\gnupg-for-java-master\build.xml:71: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\user\Desktop\MFT\gnupg-for-java-master\build.xml:63: exec returned: 2

Total time: 4 seconds
```

**Update**

I changed the `Java home` in `GNUmakefile`, Now it is throwing different error. Seems `c library` not found and this API is written for Unix system seems by reading the error message. What C library missing ?

```
    generate-jni-headers:
     [exec] C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_75/bin/javah -classpath C:\Users\user\Desktop\MFT\gnupg-for-java-master\build\classes -jni  com.freiheit.gnupg.GnuPGConte
xt  com.freiheit.gnupg.GnuPGData  com.freiheit.gnupg.GnuPGGenkeyResult  com.freiheit.gnupg.GnuPGKey  com.freiheit.gnupg.GnuPGSignature

gen-jni-library:

recompile-c-code:
     [exec] mingw32-gcc -g -Werror -Wall -Wno-deprecated-declarations -fPIC -mms-bitfields -Wl,--add-stdcall-alias  -D_REENTRANT -D_THREAD_SAFE -D_FIL
E_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DLARGEFILE_SOURCE=1 -I"C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_75/include" -I"C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_75/include/win32" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)/GNU/GnuPG/includ
e" -c GnuPGContext.c
     [exec] /bin/sh: mingw32-gcc: command not found
     [exec] make: *** [GnuPGContext.o] Error 127

BUILD FAILED
C:\Users\user\Desktop\MFT\gnupg-for-java-master\build.xml:82: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\user\Desktop\MFT\gnupg-for-java-master\build.xml:75: exec returned: 2

Total time: 7 seconds
```

Can anyone help me to solve this issue ? 
Where I'm making mistake ?

Comment: Ant does not find the `make` utility. Do you have a C compiler and toolchain installed?

Comment: I'm using windows 8 and installed java only. Never used C compiler and toolchain. How to set up them ? Can you give any idea ?

Comment: It seems whatever you exactly try to use builds GPGME on its own. Can't help you with specifics, would have to look up the requirements myself.

Comment: Thanks for the bounty, did you managed to solve the problem, I think it's just another path error. It's really sad that all of the paths are hardcoded into the makefile...

Comment: The edit was rejected before I could check it, anyway, does the script working now?

Comment: Your answer with unix path, So i changed it to windows paht and line 55-57 also with windows path. Which is working and build successful.. Thanks a lot for your time and patience to answer each and every question. :)

Comment: Hehe, I'm glad you solved it, based on the insturctions it seemed that you can build in 5 minutes, but in the end we spent a week to solve it :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I rewrote my answer because I wanted to create a complete guide.

Install GnuPG and MinGW-Get to a directory without spaces.
After you installed MinGW with !!!GUI!!!, open mingw-get, install these components:
mingw32-gcc (check all)
mingw32-libz (the dll is the most important)

[Download](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/MSYS/Base/msys-core/msys-1.0.11/) and install [MSYS](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/msys), that is a command line toolkit for running commands like make.

Then put `c:\msys\1.0\bin\`  (or wherever you installed it) on the beginning of the PATH variable. Restart eclipse or open a new cmd, and it should work.

In the build.xml:
line 21:

```
classpath="lib/junit-4.4.jar" added.(and the junit is in the lib dir)
```

In the GNUmakefile:
line 9 :

```
ALL_CFLAGS :=  -Wall -Wno-deprecated-declarations -fPIC
```

line 10:

```
ALL_CPPFLAGS = -D_REENTRANT -D_THREAD_SAFE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DLARGEFILE_SOURCE=1 \
        -I"c:/WORK/x/gnu/jdk/jdk1.8.0_25/include" -I"c:/WORK/x/gnu/jdk/jdk1.8.0_25/include/win32"
```

line 21-27:

```
  JAVA_HOME := c:/WORK/x/gnu/jdk/jdk1.8.0_25
  ALL_CFLAGS +=  -mms-bitfields -Wl,--add-stdcall-alias
  ALL_CPPFLAGS += -I"c:/WORK/x/gnu/jdk/jdk1.8.0_25/include/win32" -I"c:/WORK/x/gnu/jdk/jdk1.8.0_25/include" -I"c:/GNU/GnuPG/include"
  ALL_LDFLAGS :=  -s -shared -Wl,--enable-auto-import
  ALL_LIBS := -L"c:/GNU/GnuPG" -lgpgme-11
  GNUPG_LIB := $(BUILD_DIR)/gnupg-for-java.dll
```

line 63:

```
$(CC) $(DEBUG) $(ALL_CFLAGS) $(ALL_LDFLAGS) $^ -o "$(BUILD_DIR)/gnupg-for-java.dll" $(ALL_LIBS)
```

Summary: This is working for me and outputs the jar and dll file to the build directory. My work directory was c:/WORK/x so replace the paths where it is different. Don't use "Program Files" anywhere, as you can see I had to copy everything from there.

Comment: I followed the instructions and `make` working there and throwing some other error and build failed. Can you help me to solve this issue ? I updated the error message in the question.

Comment: Sorry for the late, I updated my question. Please check it once. Java location path is trying to pick up from older path still. Any idea where it goes wrong ?

Comment: I just realized, the makefile doesn't use the real java_home. In the jni/GNUmakefile change the line 26 to the correct value. I hope this will solve it.

Comment: I followed same instructions, this time c library missing. First i installed all MSYS libraries as you guided. But now it is still shouting. Any help to fix this issue ?

Comment: But the mingw is installed too, right? I downloaded the MinGW get, and i had to call bin/mingw-get install gcc, to get gcc. Did you do every step from the readme txt?

Comment: You shoud check all of the paths in the makefile, that all of them points to the right place. Gcc or gpg4win could be missing.

Comment: The project seems complete mess. I changed by following instructions, still facing same problem after replacing with `gcc`. In error stack, i get `C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_75/include/win32` I'm sure this path is not windows standard and unix. So the problem won't get solved. Do i need to use Cygwin to run this application in windows ? 
No easy instructions from developers of code. It's really bad.

Comment: Updated again, I hope this will work for you as well, and I completely agree with you,  this Gnupg for java is terribly undocumented regarding installation on windows.

Answer (score 3):

The error message is telling that it cannot find `mingw32-gcc` in `/bin/sh`.

You should install [mingw](http://www.mingw.org/) at first and add it to your path. Check that mingw32-gcc can be launched from the command line.

Are you running the ant script from cygwin? It's a bit strange that it is referring `/bin/sh`. Maybe you should try to run it from cygwin. Or check the build.xml file to see how mingw32-gcc is called. It must be recompile-c-code target.